# Magento - Show product attributes on Order confirmation email

Tags: php, html, magento

I need help with the following:

In Magento I have created a configurable product and assigned some simple products to it. They have an individual attribute set with individual attributes that I have created.

On the order review page, the product name as well as the options are displayed - this is fine.

On the order confirmation email, only the product's name and the SKU of the associated/ordered product is displayed. I need to display the atttributes that belong to my product as well (the attributes, that I have created to describe that specific product, like length, width, etc.).

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize the code for order confirmation email function sendNewOrderEmail().

```
  Get attributes of a ordered products and  pass this to email template .
```

Comment: Thanks, Deepa! unfortunately, I am not really familiar with coding. Could you eventually provide me with some more details / a step 2 step instruction? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is what I had to do.

```
// get array of super_attributes
$productOptions = $_item->getProductOptions();
$superAttributes = $productOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'];

// once you have super_attributes, loop through and load attribute information and output
foreach($superAttributes as $attribute => $option) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($_storeId)->setData($attribute,$option);
    $option = $product->getAttributeText($attribute);

   echo $option;
}
```

The option value for the attribute will now be output.